# How to get an Iterator of Rows using Dataframe in SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an application in SparkSQL which returns large number of rows that are very difficult to fit in memory so I will not be able to use collect function on DataFrame, is there a way using which I can get all this rows as an Iterable instaed of the entire rows as list.

I am executing this SparkSQL application using yarn-client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking transferring all the data to the driver looks a pretty bad idea and most of the time there is a better solution out there but if you really want to go with this you can use `toLocalIterator` method on a RDD:

```scala
val df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = ???
df.cache // Optional, to avoid repeated computation, see docs for details
val iter: Iterator[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]  = df.rdd.toLocalIterator
```

Comment: Kind of late to this but could you elaborate more on a few of the better solutions?

Comment: @irregular It depends on particular application but most of the time  `mapPartitions`, `foreachPartition` or similar method is more than enough. Do you have any particular use case in mind?

Comment: I'm also looking at a dataset that's too large for memory. Unfortunately I run into this error https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10189 when using toLocalIterator. So I've been looking into adding ROW_NUMBER to query through the db https://paste.pound-python.org/show/sk4bPE5P9QsKhmcYlsK0/ I'm not quite sure how to set up partitions so this is how i'm going about it atm

Comment: Uhm, what exactly this code suppose to do? :) Are you trying to do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33878701/1560062)?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation! I am trying to get a list of (sceneid, id), the sceneid and id is organized by groups of userid -> lessonid -> videoid -> createdat time so there are many database rows with many duplicates of those. I am trying to aggregate that data any duplicate userid/lessonid/videoid/createdat values will result in a few sceneid's which need to be deleted. so those for loops are going through the database rows and collecting that data. The process is slow so I wonder if partitioning would speed things up

Comment: @irregular So why not `groupBy(userid, lessonid, videoid, createdate)` and take `first(whatever-left)`. BTW Your SQL is not distributed as far as I can tell. Don't use window functions without `PARTITION BY`: https://git.io/vynqU Oh, and filters are linear. In general take a look at the question I've linked. I think this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can just use: `df.toLocalIterator`, here is the reference in Spark source code:

```
/**
 * Return an iterator that contains all of [[Row]]s in this Dataset.
 *
 * The iterator will consume as much memory as the largest partition in this Dataset.
 *
 * Note: this results in multiple Spark jobs, and if the input Dataset is the result
 * of a wide transformation (e.g. join with different partitioners), to avoid
 * recomputing the input Dataset should be cached first.
 *
 * @group action
 * @since 2.0.0
 */
def toLocalIterator(): java.util.Iterator[T] = withCallback("toLocalIterator", toDF()) { _ =>
withNewExecutionId {
  queryExecution.executedPlan.executeToIterator().map(boundEnc.fromRow).asJava
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kehe CAI for your answer but this question is quite old and I have asked this specific to spark 1.2