# How to do custom operations on GroupedData in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, grouping

I want to rewrite some of my code written with RDDs to use DataFrames. It was working quite smoothly until I found this:

```
 events
  .keyBy(row => (row.getServiceId + row.getClientCreateTimestamp + row.getClientId, row) )
  .reduceByKey((e1, e2) => if(e1.getClientSendTimestamp <= e2.getClientSendTimestamp) e1 else e2)
  .values
```

it is simple to start with

```
 events
  .groupBy(events("service_id"), events("client_create_timestamp"), events("client_id"))
```

but what's next? What if I'd like to iterate over every element in the current group? Is it even possible? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GroupedData` cannot be used directly. Data is not physically grouped and it is just a logical operation. You have to apply some variant of `agg` method for example:

```
events
 .groupBy($"service_id", $"client_create_timestamp", $"client_id")
 .min("client_send_timestamp")
```

or

```
events
 .groupBy($"service_id", $"client_create_timestamp", $"client_id")
 .agg(min($"client_send_timestamp"))
```

where `client_send_timestamp` is a column you want to aggregate.

If you want to keep information than aggregate just `join` or use Window functions - see [Find maximum row per group in Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35218882/1560062)

Spark also supports User Defined Aggregate Functions - see [How to define and use a User-Defined Aggregate Function in Spark SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32100973/1560062)

**Spark 2.0+**

You could use `Dataset.groupByKey` which exposes groups as an iterator.