# Retrieve arbitrary row for unique combination of columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data in a dataframe

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
1       desc1    v1      v3
2       desc2    v4      v2
1       desc1    v4      v2
2       desc2    v1      v3
```

I need only the first row of each unique combination of col1,col2 like below

```
Expected Output:

col1    col2    col3    col4
1       desc1    v1      v3
2       desc2    v4      v2
```

How can I achieve this in pyspark (version 1.3.1)?

I tried and achieved the same by converting the dataframe into an rdd and then applying map and reduceByKey functions and then converting back the result rdd into dataframe. Is there any other way to perform the above operation using dataframe functions?

Comment: Is there an logical order to consider ?

Comment: To make it more clear: First /Last row is not mandatory. I need distinct values of (col1,col2) along with any values of (col3,col4) from same row. I am not able to use aggregate functions like min or max, because they will bring values of col3 and col4 from different rows.

Comment: If I can introduce one more column(col5) with values of: row_number() over (partition by col1,col2 order by col1,col2 asc) , I can filter out the first rows using the new column - col5 = 1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35226857/1560062

Comment: Window functions are not available in spark 1.3.1. Is there a way to bring them in??

Comment: No, but you can use struct ordering.

Comment: @eliasah Not in 1.3.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an arbitrary row you can try to use `first` or `last` but it is far from pretty and I would seriously consider upgrading Spark:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, first

df = sc.parallelize([
  (1, "desc1", "v1", "v3"), (2, "desc2", "v4", "v2"),
  (1, "desc1", "v4", "v2"), (2, "desc2", "v1", "v3")
]).toDF(["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"])

keys = ["col1", "col2"]
values = ["col3", "col4"]
agg_exprs = [first(c).alias(c) for c in keys + ["vs_"]]
select_exprs = keys + [
    "vs_.col{0} AS {1}".format(i + 1, v) for (i, v) in enumerate(values)]

df_not_so_first = (df
  .selectExpr("struct({}) AS vs_".format(",".join(values)), *keys)
  .groupBy(*keys)
  .agg(*agg_exprs)
  .selectExpr(*select_exprs))
```

Note that in this particular context `first` **doesn't choose any specific row** and results may not be deterministic. Moreover, depending on a Spark version, individual aggregations can be scheduled separately. It means that

```
df.groupBy("col1", "col2").agg(first("col3"), first("col4"))
```

doesn't guarantee `col3` and `col4` will be selected from the same row.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used first() function and tried the following. It is working fine. 

df.groupBy(df.col1,df.col2).agg(df.col1,df.col2,first(df.col3).alias('col3'),first(df.col4).alias('col4')).show()

Comment: You shouldn't use it alone. Depending on a version and settings behavior you'll get won't be deterministic. In `groupBy` context it doesn't choose any particular row so if individual aggregations are scheduled individually there is no guarantee you get values from the same row or even the same values every time.