# how to get most frequent values of a dataframe in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, mode

I am well familiar with Pandas data frame where I use function "mode" and "groupby" to get most frequent values,like below

```
df3=df5.groupby(['band']).apply(lambda x: x.mode())
```

however I am facing some difficulties to get in PySpark.

I have a spark data frame as follows:

```
band      A3    A5  status
4G_band1800 12  18  TRUE
4G_band1800 12  18  FALSE
4G_band1800 10  18  TRUE
4G_band1800 12  12  TRUE
4g_band2300 6   24  FALSE
4g_band2300 6   22  FALSE
4g_band2300 6   24  FALSE
4g_band2300 3   24  TRUE
```

[Screenshot of above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XHhJ.png)

What I want is as follows:

```
band      A3    A5  status
4G_band1800 12  18  TRUE
4g_band2300 6   24  FALSE
```

[Screenshot of above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pHQS.png)

I have tried all possible combinations but haven't got any reasonable output.
Please suggest a way.

Comment: can you share your input data in a format that others can comprehend?

Comment: hi, i updated the question using images.. image one is input of data frame and image 2 what i want in output

Comment: no images please

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience .. now its updated with proper data frame.

Comment: the column "band" has two unique different values as 4g_band2300 and 4g_band1800 and it has multiple values for other columns. i need most frequent values of those column required for this two bands. in Pandas i generally use mode function and groupby function like following: `df3=df5.groupby(['band']).apply(lambda x: x.mode())`

Comment: but what is the solution in PySpark..

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36695251/4964651 it's gunna be quite expensive tho.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without defining your own `UDAF`, you might define a mode function (udf) and use it with `collect_list` as follows:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
@F.udf
def mode(x):
    from collections import Counter
    return Counter(x).most_common(1)[0][0]

cols = ['A3', 'A5', 'status']
agg_expr = [mode(F.collect_list(col)).alias(col) for col in cols]
df.groupBy('band').agg(*agg_expr).show()

+-----------+---+---+------+
|       band| A3| A5|status|
+-----------+---+---+------+
|4G_band1800| 12| 18|  true|
|4g_band2300|  6| 24| false|
+-----------+---+---+------+
```

Comment: Works fine for string/number types but not for date type