# Find modal value for each id in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, aggregate

I have a pyspark dataframe of ~1.7billion rows with the schema:

```
INPUT SCHEMA
id  
ip  
datetime
```

and I am trying to find the modal ip for each id

I currently have a function where I make a separate table of

```
INT TABLE
id
ip
number_of_records
```

and then filter that for the modal ip

This seems incredibly slow and bulky, what is a more efficient way to get the modal ip for each ip?

```
Proposed Output Schema
id
modal_ip
```

Thanks all!

Comment: What do you mean by "modal ip"?

Comment: I think this is pretty much what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36695251/5368910

Comment: @absolutelydevastated the ip address that has the most records associated with it for each id. ie if there is ip1 with 3 records for that id and ip2 with 5 records on that id then choose ip2

Comment: @timchap That is basically exactly what I have, I was looking for a more elegant/faster solution that does not require so much heavy lifting here

Comment: What if there are multiple modes?

Comment: then choose both!

Comment: You could reduce the requirement to sort and then filter if you wanted: instead, you could take each id-grouped partition and just iterate over it once to find the most-prevalent IP. e.g. a `reduceByKey` with `key=(ID, IP)` and `f=lambda a, b: max(a, b)`. This won't find multiple modes though.

Comment: @timchap that looks interesting, and there arent very many ties, could you show that in code?

Comment: I think the `groupBy`, `count` then `window` method is already the best way to go about doing this. Although I'd suggest that you `rank` the IPs instead of taking `row_number`. What is it that you don't like about that solution?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comments, here's a solution which demonstrates how you can technically achieve this in two passses of the data - one to count, and one to reduce and find (multiple) modes. I've implemented the second part with the RDD API  - translating into the DataFrame API is left to the reader ;) (tbh I don't know if it's even possible to do custom aggregations with multiple output rows like this):

```
from pyspark.sql import types

import pandas as pd

from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql.functions import PandasUDFType

# Example data
data = [
    (0 ,'12.2.25.68'),
    (0 ,'12.2.25.68'),
    (0 ,'12.2.25.43'),
    (1 ,'62.251.0.149'),  # This ID has two modes
    (1 ,'62.251.0.140'),
]

schema = types.StructType([
    types.StructField('id', types.IntegerType()),
    types.StructField('ip', types.StringType()),
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

# Count id/ip pairs
df = df.groupBy('id', 'ip').count()

def find_modes(a, b):
    """
    Reducing function to find modes (can return multiple). 

    a and b are lists of Row
    """
    if a[0]['count'] > b[0]['count']:
        return a
    if a[0]['count'] < b[0]['count']:
        return b
    return a + b

result = (
    df.rdd
    .map(lambda row: (row['id'], [row]))
    .reduceByKey(find_modes)
    .collectAsMap()
)
```

Result:

```
{0: [Row(id=0, ip='12.2.25.68', count=2)],
 1: [Row(id=1, ip='62.251.0.149', count=1),
 Row(id=1, ip='62.251.0.140', count=1)]}
```

Small caveat to this approach: because I aggregate repeated modes in-memory, if you have many different IPs with the same count for a single ID, you do risk OOM issues. For this particular application, I'd say it's very unlikely (e.g. a single user probably won't have 1 million different IPs, all with 1 event).

But I tend to agree with @absolutelydevastated, the simplest solution is probably the one you have already, even if it has an extra pass of the data. But you should probably avoid doing a `sort`/`rank` and instead just seek the max count in the window if possible.