# Get row with maximum value from groupby with several columns in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe similar to

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, first

rdd = sc.parallelize(
[
(0, "A", 223,"201603", "PORT"), 
(0, "A", 22,"201602", "PORT"), 
(0, "A", 22,"201603", "PORT"), 
(0, "C", 22,"201605", "PORT"), 
(0, "D", 422,"201601", "DOCK"), 
(0, "D", 422,"201602", "DOCK"), 
(0, "C", 422,"201602", "DOCK"), 
(1,"B", 3213,"201602", "DOCK"), 
(1,"A", 3213,"201602", "DOCK"), 
(1,"C", 3213,"201602", "PORT"), 
(1,"B", 3213,"201601", "PORT"), 
(1,"B", 3213,"201611", "PORT"), 
(1,"B", 3213,"201604", "PORT"), 
(3,"D", 3999,"201601", "PORT"), 
(3,"C", 323,"201602", "PORT"), 
(3,"C", 323,"201602", "PORT"), 
(3,"C", 323,"201605", "DOCK"), 
(3,"A", 323,"201602", "DOCK"), 
(2,"C", 2321,"201601", "DOCK"),
(2,"A", 2321,"201602", "PORT")
]
)
df_data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["id","type", "cost", "date", "ship"])
```

and I need to aggregate by `id` and `type` and get the highest occurrence of `ship` per group. For example,

```
grouped = df_data.groupby('id','type', 'ship').count()
```

has a column with the number of times of each group:

```
+---+----+----+-----+
| id|type|ship|count|
+---+----+----+-----+
|  3|   A|DOCK|    1|
|  0|   D|DOCK|    2|
|  3|   C|PORT|    2|
|  0|   A|PORT|    3|
|  1|   A|DOCK|    1|
|  1|   B|PORT|    3|
|  3|   C|DOCK|    1|
|  3|   D|PORT|    1|
|  1|   B|DOCK|    1|
|  1|   C|PORT|    1|
|  2|   C|DOCK|    1|
|  0|   C|PORT|    1|
|  0|   C|DOCK|    1|
|  2|   A|PORT|    1|
+---+----+----+-----+
```

and I need to get

```
+---+----+----+-----+
| id|type|ship|count|
+---+----+----+-----+
|  0|   D|DOCK|    2|
|  0|   A|PORT|    3|
|  1|   A|DOCK|    1|
|  1|   B|PORT|    3|
|  2|   C|DOCK|    1|
|  2|   A|PORT|    1|
|  3|   C|PORT|    2|
|  3|   A|DOCK|    1|
+---+----+----+-----+
```

I tried to use a combination of

```
grouped.groupby('id', 'type', 'ship')\
.agg({'count':'max'}).orderBy('max(count)', ascending=False).\
groupby('id', 'type', 'ship').agg({'ship':'first'})
```

But it fails. Is there a way to get the maximum row from a count of a group by?

On pandas this oneliner does the job:

```
df_pd = df_data.toPandas()
df_pd_t = df_pd[df_pd['count'] == df_pd.groupby(['id','type', ])['count'].transform(max)]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find maximum row per group in Spark DataFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218882/find-maximum-row-per-group-in-spark-dataframe)

Comment: The indicated post has only one dimension on the group by. It is not clear how to expand it with the three methods on that post.

Comment: It doesn't affect answer. Just more to put in  partitionBy or groupBy.

Comment: Not really. I tried to do the join method and the window method and they don´t work if the group by has more than one dimension - they only consider the first one.

Comment: Both work for me. Are you sure you use correct conditions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your expected output, it seems you are only grouping by `id` and `ship` - since you already have distinct values in `grouped` - and consequently drop duplicate elements based on the columns `id`, `ship` and `count`, sorted by `type`.

To accomplish this, we can use `Window` functions:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import rank, col

window = (Window
          .partitionBy(grouped['id'],
                       grouped['ship'])
          .orderBy(grouped['count'].desc(), grouped['type']))


(grouped
 .select('*', rank()
         .over(window)
         .alias('rank')) 
  .filter(col('rank') == 1)
  .orderBy(col('id'))
  .dropDuplicates(['id', 'ship', 'count'])
  .drop('rank')
  .show())
+---+----+----+-----+
| id|type|ship|count|
+---+----+----+-----+
|  0|   D|DOCK|    2|
|  0|   A|PORT|    3|
|  1|   A|DOCK|    1|
|  1|   B|PORT|    3|
|  2|   C|DOCK|    1|
|  2|   A|PORT|    1|
|  3|   A|DOCK|    1|
|  3|   C|PORT|    2|
+---+----+----+-----+
```