# Getting latest entry for each group in dataframe when using Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I've researched a little on this and found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35226857/6092420) for general Spark applications. However, in structured streaming, you cannot do a join between 2 streaming dataframes (therefore a self join is not possible) and sorting functions cannot be used as well. So is there a way to get the latest entry for each group at all? (I'm on Spark 2.2)

UPDATE: **Assuming the dataframe rows are already sorted by time already**, we can just take the last entry using for each required row using `groupBy` then `agg` with the `pyspark.sql.functions.last` function.

Comment: [Spark 2.3](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) Structured Streaming is supporting some cases of joins. You may refer. I think your requirement can be met using the window functions with the constraints mentioned in the doc.

Comment: I'm actually running on Spark 2.2. Unfortunately.