# Udf not working

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

can you help me to optimize this code and make it work?
this is original data:

```
+--------------------+-------------+
|       original_name|medicine_name|
+--------------------+-------------+
|         Venlafaxine|  Venlafaxine|
|    Lacrifilm 5mg/ml|    Lacrifilm|
|    Lacrifilm 5mg/ml|         null|
|         Venlafaxine|         null|
|Vitamin D10,000IU...|         null|
|         paracetamol|         null|
|            mucolite|         null|
```

I'm expect to get data like this

```
+--------------------+-------------+
|       original_name|medicine_name|
+--------------------+-------------+
|         Venlafaxine|  Venlafaxine|
|    Lacrifilm 5mg/ml|    Lacrifilm|
|    Lacrifilm 5mg/ml|    Lacrifilm|
|         Venlafaxine|  Venlafaxine|
|Vitamin D10,000IU...|         null|
|         paracetamol|         null|
|            mucolite|         null|
```

This is the code:

```
distinct_df = spark.sql("select distinct medicine_name as medicine_name from medicine where medicine_name is not null")
distinct_df.createOrReplaceTempView("distinctDF")

def getMax(num1, num2):
    pmax = (num1>=num2)*num1+(num2>num1)*num2
    return pmax

def editDistance(s1, s2):
    ed = (getMax(length(s1), length(s2)) - levenshtein(s1,s2))/
          getMax(length(s1), length(s2))
    return ed

editDistanceUdf = udf(lambda x,y: editDistance(x,y), FloatType())

def getSimilarity(str):
    res = spark.sql("select medicine_name, editDistanceUdf('str', medicine_name) from distinctDf where editDistanceUdf('str', medicine_name)>=0.85 order by 2")
    res['medicine_name'].take(1)
    return res

getSimilarityUdf = udf(lambda x: getSimilarity(x), StringType())
res_df = df.withColumn('m_name', when((df.medicine_name.isNull)|(df.medicine_name.=="null")),getSimilarityUdf(df.original_name)
.otherwise(df.medicine_name)).show()
```

now i'm getting error:

> command_part = REFERENCE_TYPE + parameter._get_object_id()
>   AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bunch of problems with your code:

- You cannot use `SparkSession` or distributed objects in the `udf`. So `getSimilarity` just cannot work. If you want to compare objects like this you have to `join`.
- If `length` and `levenshtein` come from `pyspark.sql.functions` there cannot be used inside `UserDefinedFunctions`. There are designed to generate SQL expressions, mapping from `*Column` to `Column`.
- Column `isNull` is a method not `property` so should be called:

  ```
  df.medicine_name.isNull()
  ```
- Following

  ```
  df.medicine_name.=="null"
  ```

  is not a syntactically valid Python (looks like Scala calque) and would throw compiler exceptions.
- If `SparkSession` access was allowed in an `UserDefinedFunction` this wouldn't be a valid substitution

  ```
  spark.sql("select medicine_name, editDistanceUdf('str', medicine_name) from distinctDf where editDistanceUdf('str', medicine_name)>=0.85 order by 2")
  ```

  You should use string formatting methods

  ```
  spark.sql("select medicine_name, editDistanceUdf({str}, medicine_name) from distinctDf where editDistanceUdf({str}, medicine_name)>=0.85 order by 2".format(str=str))
  ```
- Maybe some other problems, but since you didn't provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), anything else would be pure guessing.

When you fix smaller mistakes you have two choices:

- Use `crossJoin`:

  ```
  combined = df.alias("left").crossJoin(spark.table("distinctDf").alias("right"))
  ```

  Then apply `udf`, filter, and one of the methods listed in [Find maximum row per group in Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35218882) to closest match in group.
- Use built-in approximate matching tools as explained in [Efficient string matching in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43938672)