# Pyspark equivalent for df.groupby('id').resample('D').last() in pandas

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, group-by, pyspark, grouping

I have a large table like

[image]

I want to change it to a new table : id, date, last_state .

It is very easy by pandas :

```
df['time_create'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_create'])
df = df.set_index('time_create')
df = df.sort_index()
df = df.groupby('id').resample('D').last().reset_index()
```

But it is very hard to implement by pyspark.

I knew:

1. Resample equivalent in pysaprk is groupby + window :

   ```
   grouped = df.groupBy('store_product_id', window("time_create", "1 day")).agg(sum("Production").alias('Sum Production'))
   ```

   here groupby store_product_id , resample in day and calculate sum
2. Group by and find first or last:

   refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/35226857/1637673

   ```
   w = Window().partitionBy("store_product_id").orderBy(col("time_create").desc())
   (df
     .withColumn("rn", row_number().over(w))
     .where(col("rn") == 1)
     .select("store_product_id", "time_create", "state"))
   ```

   This groupby id and get the last row order by time_create .

However what I need is groupby id, resample by day,then get last row order by time_create .

I know this problem may could be solved if I use pandas udf ,  [Applying UDFs on GroupedData in PySpark (with functioning python example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006395/applying-udfs-on-groupeddata-in-pyspark-with-functioning-python-example)

But is there any way to do this just by pyspark ?

Comment: Cant you just include the day in your window? Something like `Window().partitionBy("store_product_id", dayofmonth(col("time_create"))).orderBy(col("time_create").desc())`

Comment: @gaw Sounds right . I forgot `partitionBy` can take multiple columns . In that case, shouldn't use `dayofmonth`, need add a new date column from `time_create` . But isn't the partitions too many ? My dataset across 2016 to 2019 with over 200 million rows .

Comment: I think this should still be possible. In this 4 years you have like ~1400 days and different products but spark should be able to handle this I think. Just make sure to use the day with month and year then. I applied a window on a big proxy dataset and partitioned this by client-ip and destination url and it still worked. I think I had much more partitions for this usecase :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `partitionBy("store_product_id", "date")` do the trick

```
w = Window().partitionBy("store_product_id", "date").orderBy(col("time_create").desc())
x = (df
    .withColumn("rn", row_number().over(w))
    .where(col("rn") == 1)
    .select("store_product_id", "time_create", "state"))
```