# How do I remove duplicate rows from a table on the basis of Primary keys?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Table loaded in Dataframe and I tried to use groupBy with PKs.

```
df_remitInsert = spark.sql("""SELECT * FROM trac_analytics.mainremitdata""")
df_remitInsert_filter = df_remitInsert.groupBy("LoanID_Serv", "LoanNumber", "Month").count().filter("count > 1").drop('count')
```

where, `"LoanID_Serv", "LoanNumber", "Month"` are my Primary Keys.

I want to achieve entire data from `df_remitInsert` which are deduplicated w.r.t Primary Keys.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218882/find-maximum-row-per-group-in-spark-dataframe) help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dropDuplicates](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropDuplicates.html) method.

```
df_remitInsert_filter = df_remitInsert.dropDuplicates(['LoanID_Serv', 'LoanNumber', 'Month'])
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the latest row?