# SPARK DataFrame: select the first 3 rows of each group

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm stuck with a similar use case as in [SPARK DataFrame: select the first row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878370/spark-dataframe-select-the-first-row-of-each-group). Only difference is that I need to select the first 3 rows of each group. The `agg` function allows me to select the top value with the help of `max` function or by applying `sort` initially and then using the `first` function.

Is there way to achieve it using `agg` function after doing a `groupby`? If not, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Please illustrate your question with example dataset, attempted code and expected output.

Answer (score 9):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{row_number, max, broadcast}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

df=Dataframe....

val w = Window.partitionBy($"groupColumn").orderBy($"AnyColumn".desc)

val dfTop = df.withColumn("rn", row_number.over(w)).where($"rn" ===> 3).drop("rn") 
dfTop.show
```

Comment: It should be `row_number` instead of `rowNumber`

Comment: can you explain this ===> operator?

Answer (score 2):

Use window functions with `row_number` as in the linked question but replace:

```
.where($"rn" === 1)
```

with

```
.where($"rn" <= 3)
```

Comment: This is the functionality and code provided in Apache DataFu's [dedupTopN method](https://github.com/apache/datafu/blob/master/datafu-spark/src/main/scala/datafu/spark/SparkDFUtils.scala#L164)

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to iterate through the result list of values populated from groupByKey() and then extracting topN records and appending those values in a new list.
Following is the working example, you can execute it on Cloudera VM as I have used Cloudera sample data set. Before executing it, make sure that you have product RDD generated from products table which exists in mySql - retail_db database.

getTopN function ->

```
def getTopN(rec: (String, Iterable[String]), topN: Int): Iterable[String] = {
          var prodPrices: List[Float] = List()
          var topNPrices: List[Float] = List()
          var sortedRecs: List[String] = List()
          for(i <- rec._2) {
            prodPrices = prodPrices:+ i.split(",")(4).toFloat
          }
          topNPrices = prodPrices.distinct.sortBy(k => -k).take(topN)
          sortedRecs = rec._2.toList.sortBy(k => -k.split(",")(4).toFloat) 
          var x: List[String] = List()
          for(i <- sortedRecs) {
            if(topNPrices.contains(i.split(",")(4).toFloat))
              x = x:+ i 
          }
          return x
        }
```

Main code ->

```
##code to generate products RDD

val productsMap = products.
  map(rec => (rec.split(",")(1), rec))
productsMap.
  groupByKey().
  flatMap(x => getTopN(x, 3)).
  collect().
  foreach(println)
```