# What is the similar alternative to reduceByKey in DataFrames

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Give following code

```
case class Contact(name: String, phone: String)
case class Person(name: String, ts:Long, contacts: Seq[Contact])

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
val people = sqlContext.read.format("orc").load("people")
```

What is the best way to dedupe users by its timestamp
So the user with max ts will stay at collection?
In spark using RDD I would run something like this

```
rdd.reduceByKey(_ maxTS _)
```

and would add the maxTS method to Person or add implicits ...

```
def maxTS(that: Person):Person =
that.ts > ts match {
  case true => that
  case false => this
}
```

Is it possible to do the same at DataFrames? and will that be the similar performance? 
We are using spark 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Window functions, I'm assuming that the key is `name`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{rowNumber, max, broadcast}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val df = // convert to DataFrame
val win = Window.partitionBy('name).orderBy('ts.desc)
df.withColumn("personRank", rowNumber.over(win))
  .where('personRank === 1).drop("personRank")
```

For each person it will create personRank - each person with given name will have unique number, person with the latest ts will have the lowest rank, equal  to 1. The you drop temporary rank

Comment: Answer inspired by this answer by Maciej: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878370/spark-dataframe-select-the-first-row-of-each-group?rq=1 Please upvote that answer if you are upvoting mine ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what is the performance of that? it should first shuffle all data, than per each key order the duplicates ...? or it has some optimizations underground?

Comment: @Julias It will do only one exchange. according to `explain()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do a groupBy and use your preferred aggregation method like sum, max etc.

```
df.groupBy($"name").agg(sum($"tx").alias("maxTS"))
```

Comment: But this doesn't give me the whole record, only the aggregated one.