# Group by column "grp" and compress DataFrame - (take last not null value for each column ordering by column "ord")

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate-functions, aggregation

Assuming I have the following DataFrame:

```
+---+--------+---+----+----+
|grp|null_col|ord|col1|col2|
+---+--------+---+----+----+
|  1|    null|  3|null|  11|
|  2|    null|  2| xxx|  22|
|  1|    null|  1| yyy|null|
|  2|    null|  7|null|  33|
|  1|    null| 12|null|null|
|  2|    null| 19|null|  77|
|  1|    null| 10| s13|null|
|  2|    null| 11| a23|null|
+---+--------+---+----+----+
```

here is the same sample DF with comments, sorted by `grp` and `ord`:

```
scala> df.orderBy("grp", "ord").show
+---+--------+---+----+----+
|grp|null_col|ord|col1|col2|
+---+--------+---+----+----+
|  1|    null|  1| yyy|null|
|  1|    null|  3|null|  11|   # grp:1 - last value for `col2` (11)
|  1|    null| 10| s13|null|   # grp:1 - last value for `col1` (s13)
|  1|    null| 12|null|null|   # grp:1 - last values for `null_col`, `ord`
|  2|    null|  2| xxx|  22|   
|  2|    null|  7|null|  33|   
|  2|    null| 11| a23|null|   # grp:2 - last value for `col1` (a23)
|  2|    null| 19|null|  77|   # grp:2 - last values for `null_col`, `ord`, `col2`
+---+--------+---+----+----+
```

I would like to compress it. I.e. to group it by column `"grp"` and for each group, sort rows by the `"ord"` column and take the last `not null` value in each column (if there is one).

```
+---+--------+---+----+----+
|grp|null_col|ord|col1|col2|
+---+--------+---+----+----+
|  1|    null| 12| s13|  11|
|  2|    null| 19| a23|  77|
+---+--------+---+----+----+
```

I've seen the following similar questions:

- [How to select the first row of each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878370/how-to-select-the-first-row-of-each-group)
- [How to find first non-null values in groups? (secondary sorting using dataset api)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986965/how-to-find-first-non-null-values-in-groups-secondary-sorting-using-dataset-ap?rq=1)

but my real DataFrame has over 250 columns, so I need a solution where I don't have to specify all the columns explicitly.

I can't wrap my head around it...

---

**MCVE: how to create a sample DataFrame:**

1. create local file "/tmp/data.txt" and copy and paste there a context of the DataFrame (as it's posted above)
2. define [function `readSparkOutput()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48454013/5741205):
3. parse "/tmp/data.txt" to DataFrame:

   ```
   val df = readSparkOutput("file:///tmp/data.txt")
   ```

---

**UPDATE:**  I think it should be similar to the following SQL:

```
SELECT
  grp, ord, null_col, col1, col2
FROM (
    SELECT
      grp,
      ord,
      FIRST(null_col) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY ord DESC) as null_col,
      FIRST(col1) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY ord DESC) as col1,
      FIRST(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY ord DESC) as col2,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY ord DESC) as rn
    FROM table_name) as v
WHERE v.rn = 1;
```

> how can we **dynamically** generate such a Spark query?

I tried the following *simplified* approach:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val win = Window
  .partitionBy("grp")
  .orderBy($"ord".desc)

val cols = df.columns.map(c => first(c, ignoreNulls=true).over(win).as(c))
```

which produces:

```
scala> cols
res23: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Array(first(grp, true) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY ord DESC NULLS LAST UnspecifiedFrame) AS `grp`, first(null_col, true) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY ord DESC NULLS LAST UnspecifiedFrame) AS `null_col`, first(ord, true) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY ord DESC NULLS LAST UnspecifiedFrame) AS `ord`, first(col1, true) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY ord DESC NULLS LAST UnspecifiedFrame) AS `col1`, first(col2, true) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY ord DESC NULLS LAST UnspecifiedFrame) AS `col2`)
```

but i couldn't pass it to `df.select`:

```
scala> df.select(cols.head, cols.tail: _*).show
<console>:34: error: no `: _*' annotation allowed here
(such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)
       df.select(cols.head, cols.tail: _*).show
```

another attempt:

```
scala> df.select(cols.map(col): _*).show
<console>:34: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String => org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column => ?
       df.select(cols.map(col): _*).show
```

Comment: Well I guess you could write a function that accepts a DF and a group by column name, you could then dynamically create a select statement by getting the remaining columns from the DF schema that selects the max of each column.

Comment: @TerryDactyl, thanks for the advice! Unfortunately `max()` wouldn't give me what I need. I need a last (in terms of the "ord" columns) not null value. And I still don't see how can I make it dynamically. I would appreciate if you could put it in the answer

Comment: @MaxU in pyspark, I *think* `df.groupBy("grp").agg(*[last(c, True).alias(c) for c in df.columns if c!= "grp"]).show()` gives you what you want. Don't know how to translate that into scala. The function `last` takes a second boolean argument `ignorenulls` which defaults to `False`.

Comment: @pault, thank you for the hint! Unfortunately it ignores the order within each group, so it won't produce desired output.

Comment: The correct syntax to use `cols` here is the following : `df.select(cols: _*)`

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not return what you want...

Comment: @eliasah, thank you for your comment. Do you have an idea how to get desired data set dynamically?

Comment: I'm looking into it. I think that LeoC's approach is good. It's all about column selection thought.

Comment: @MaxU I've added an answer about how I would do this. Hope it helps !

Comment: If you have a sec, please do consider weighing in on my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/how-do-i-slice-or-filter-mutliindex-dataframe-levels thanks :)

Comment: @coldspeed, sure, it’s a great job! :)

Comment: Thanks Max, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with same approach like @LeoC, but I believe that there is no need to manipulate column names as string  and I would go with a more spark-sql like answer.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, first, last}

val win = Window.partitionBy("grp").orderBy(col("ord")).rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)

// In case there is more than one group column
val nonAggCols = Seq("grp")

// Select columns to aggregate on
val cols: Seq[String] = df.columns.diff(nonAggCols).toSeq

// Map over selection and apply fct
val aggregations: Seq[Column] = cols.map(c => first(col(c), ignoreNulls = true).as(c))

// I'd rather cache the following step as it might get expensive
val step1 = cols.foldLeft(df)((acc, c) => acc.withColumn(c, last(col(c), ignoreNulls = true).over(win))).cache

// Finally we can aggregate our results as followed
val results = step1.groupBy(nonAggCols.head, nonAggCols.tail: _*).agg(aggregations.head, aggregations.tail: _*)

results.show
// +---+--------+---+----+----+
// |grp|null_col|ord|col1|col2|
// +---+--------+---+----+----+
// |  1|    null| 12| s13|  11|
// |  2|    null| 19| a23|  77|
// +---+--------+---+----+----+
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:** The reason you are not getting the same results is because the reader that you are using isn't correct.

It interprets `null` from the file as a string and not a `null`; i.e :

```
scala> df.filter('col1.isNotNull).show
// +---+--------+---+----+----+
// |grp|null_col|ord|col1|col2|
// +---+--------+---+----+----+
// |  1|    null|  3|null|  11|
// |  2|    null|  2| xxx|  22|
// |  1|    null|  1| yyy|null|
// |  2|    null|  7|null|  33|
// |  1|    null| 12|null|null|
// |  2|    null| 19|null|  77|
// |  1|    null| 10| s13|null|
// |  2|    null| 11| a23|null|
// +---+--------+---+----+----+
```

Here is my version of `readSparkOutput` :

```
def readSparkOutput(filePath: String): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = {
  val step1 = spark.read
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("delimiter", "|")
    .option("parserLib", "UNIVOCITY")
    .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true")
    .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "true")
    .option("comment", "+")
    .csv(filePath)

  val step2 = step1.select(step1.columns.filterNot(_.startsWith("_c")).map(step1(_)): _*)

  val columns = step2.columns
  columns.foldLeft(step2)((acc, c) => acc.withColumn(c, when(col(c) =!= "null" or col(c).isNotNull, col(c))))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following approach that applies Window function `last(c, ignoreNulls=true)` ordered by "ord" per "grp" to each of the selected columns; followed by a `groupBy("grp")` to fetch the `first` [agg(colFcnMap)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset@agg(exprs:Map[String,String]):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) result:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df0 = Seq(
  (1, 3, None, Some(11)),
  (2, 2, Some("aaa"), Some(22)),
  (1, 1, Some("s12"), None),
  (2, 7, None, Some(33)),
  (1, 12, None, None),
  (2, 19, None, Some(77)),
  (1, 10, Some("s13"), None),
  (2, 11, Some("a23"), None)
).toDF("grp", "ord", "col1", "col2")

val df = df0.withColumn("null_col", lit(null))

df.orderBy("grp", "ord").show
// +---+---+----+----+--------+
// |grp|ord|col1|col2|null_col|
// +---+---+----+----+--------+
// |  1|  1| s12|null|    null|
// |  1|  3|null|  11|    null|
// |  1| 10| s13|null|    null|
// |  1| 12|null|null|    null|
// |  2|  2| aaa|  22|    null|
// |  2|  7|null|  33|    null|
// |  2| 11| a23|null|    null|
// |  2| 19|null|  77|    null|
// +---+---+----+----+--------+

val win = Window.partitionBy("grp").orderBy("ord").
  rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)

val nonAggCols = Array("grp")
val cols = df.columns.diff(nonAggCols)  // Columns to be aggregated

val colFcnMap = cols.zip(Array.fill(cols.size)("first")).toMap
// colFcnMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] =
//   Map(ord -> first, col1 -> first, col2 -> first, null_col -> first)

cols.foldLeft(df)((acc, c) =>
    acc.withColumn(c, last(c, ignoreNulls=true).over(win))
  ).
  groupBy("grp").agg(colFcnMap).
  select(col("grp") :: colFcnMap.toList.map{case (c, f) => col(s"$f($c)").as(c)}: _*).
  show
// +---+---+----+----+--------+
// |grp|ord|col1|col2|null_col|
// +---+---+----+----+--------+
// |  1| 12| s13|  11|    null|
// |  2| 19| a23|  77|    null|
// +---+---+----+----+--------+
```

Note that the final `select` is for stripping the function name (in this case `first()`) from the aggregated column names.

Comment: Thank you for your help! In my real DF I have more than 250 columns with different names (they don’t start with “col”) and some of columns will contain only NULLs, like in my sample data set. Do you know how can I adapt your method in this case? PS the “ord” column should also be present in the output data set.

Comment: @MaxU, depending on the actual column selection criteria, there're various ways to come up with the selected columns.  For example, if most of the columns are to be aggregated, one could assemble the list of columns that aren't to be aggregated and apply `diff` to exclude them, as shown in the expanded answer.

Comment: we are getting closer, thank you! :) Somehow I'm getting different resulting data set (`'col1': [null, null], 'col2': [null, 77]`, other columns are OK). I couldn't reproduce your results neither with my file nor with the sample data set from your answer...

Comment: @MaxU, not sure why you're getting different result.  I've just executed the exact code again with my sample dataset on a freshly restarted Spark Shell (v.2.2.1) and the result remains the same as that in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have worked something out, here is the code and output

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df0 = Seq(
  (1, 3, None, Some(11)),
  (2, 2, Some("aaa"), Some(22)),
  (1, 1, Some("s12"), None),
  (2, 7, None, Some(33)),
  (1, 12, None, None),
  (2, 19, None, Some(77)),
  (1, 10, Some("s13"), None),
  (2, 11, Some("a23"), None)
).toDF("grp", "ord", "col1", "col2")

df0.show()

//+---+---+----+----+
//|grp|ord|col1|col2|
//+---+---+----+----+
//|  1|  3|null|  11|
//|  2|  2| aaa|  22|
//|  1|  1| s12|null|
//|  2|  7|null|  33|
//|  1| 12|null|null|
//|  2| 19|null|  77|
//|  1| 10| s13|null|
//|  2| 11| a23|null|
//+---+---+----+----+
```

Ordering the data on first 2 columns

```
val df1 = df0.select("grp", "ord", "col1", "col2").orderBy("grp", "ord")

df1.show()

//+---+---+----+----+
//|grp|ord|col1|col2|
//+---+---+----+----+
//|  1|  1| s12|null|
//|  1|  3|null|  11|
//|  1| 10| s13|null|
//|  1| 12|null|null|
//|  2|  2| aaa|  22|
//|  2|  7|null|  33|
//|  2| 11| a23|null|
//|  2| 19|null|  77|
//+---+---+----+----+

val df2 = df1.groupBy("grp").agg(max("ord").alias("ord"),collect_set("col1").alias("col1"),collect_set("col2").alias("col2"))

val df3 = df2.withColumn("new_col1",$"col1".apply(size($"col1").minus(1))).withColumn("new_col2",$"col2".apply(size($"col2").minus(1)))

df3.show()

//+---+---+----------+------------+--------+--------+
//|grp|ord|      col1|        col2|new_col1|new_col2|
//+---+---+----------+------------+--------+--------+
//|  1| 12|[s12, s13]|        [11]|     s13|      11|
//|  2| 19|[aaa, a23]|[33, 22, 77]|     a23|      77|
//+---+---+----------+------------+--------+--------+
```

You can drop the columns you don't need by using *.drop("column_name")*

Answer (score 2):

So here we are grouping by a and selecting the max of all other columns in the group:

```
scala> val df = List((1,2,11), (1,1,1), (2,1,4), (2,3,5)).toDF("a", "b", "c")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, b: int ... 1 more field]

scala> val aggCols = df.schema.map(_.name).filter(_ != "a").map(colName => sum(col(colName)).alias(s"max_$colName"))
aggCols: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = List(sum(b) AS `max_b`, sum(c) AS `max_c`)

scala> df.groupBy(col("a")).agg(aggCols.head, aggCols.tail: _*)
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, max_b: bigint ... 1 more field]
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your solution (i've changed the aggregation function: `sum()` --> `last()`), but it doesn't work as expected with NULL's. Could you please give it a try with my sample data set?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer (and hopefully my bounty!!!)

```
scala> val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(
     | (1,null.asInstanceOf[String],3,null.asInstanceOf[String],new Integer(11)),
     | (2,null.asInstanceOf[String],2,new String("xxx"),new Integer(22)),
     | (1,null.asInstanceOf[String],1,new String("yyy"),null.asInstanceOf[Integer]),
     | (2,null.asInstanceOf[String],7,null.asInstanceOf[String],new Integer(33)),
     | (1,null.asInstanceOf[String],12,null.asInstanceOf[String],null.asInstanceOf[Integer]),
     | (2,null.asInstanceOf[String],19,null.asInstanceOf[String],new Integer(77)),
     | (1,null.asInstanceOf[String],10,new String("s13"),null.asInstanceOf[Integer]),
     | (2,null.asInstanceOf[String],11,new String("a23"),null.asInstanceOf[Integer]))).toDF("grp","null_col","ord","col1","col2")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [grp: int, null_col: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> df.show
+---+--------+---+----+----+
|grp|null_col|ord|col1|col2|
+---+--------+---+----+----+
|  1|    null|  3|null|  11|
|  2|    null|  2| xxx|  22|
|  1|    null|  1| yyy|null|
|  2|    null|  7|null|  33|
|  1|    null| 12|null|null|
|  2|    null| 19|null|  77|
|  1|    null| 10| s13|null|
|  2|    null| 11| a23|null|
+---+--------+---+----+----+
```

//Create window specification

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

scala> val win = Window.partitionBy("grp").orderBy($"ord".desc)
win: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec@71878833
```

//Use foldLeft with first over window specification over all columns and take distinct

```
scala> val result = df.columns.foldLeft(df)((df, colName) => df.withColumn(colName, first(colName, ignoreNulls=true).over(win).as(colName))).distinct
result: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [grp: int, null_col: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> result.show
+---+--------+---+----+----+
|grp|null_col|ord|col1|col2|
+---+--------+---+----+----+
|  1|    null| 12| s13|  11|
|  2|    null| 19| a23|  77|
+---+--------+---+----+----+
```

Hope this helps.