# More convenient way to reproduce pyspark sample

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Most of the questions about spark are used `show` as code example without the code that generates the dataframe, like this:

```
df.show()
+-------+--------+----------+
|USER_ID|location| timestamp|
+-------+--------+----------+
|      1|    1001|1265397099|
|      1|    6022|1275846679|
|      1|    1041|1265368299|
+-------+--------+----------+
```

How can I reproduce this code in my programming environment without rewriting it manually? pyspark have some equivalent of `read_clipboard` in pandas?

---

### Edit

The lack of a function to import data into my environment is a big obstacle for me to help others with pyspark in Stackoverflow.

So **my question is:**

What is the most convenient way to reproduce data pasted in stackoverflow from `show` command into my environment?

Comment: Is this what you want convert panda to dataframe ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513355/converting-pandas-dataframe-into-spark-dataframe-error

Comment: @howie This can be a part of the answer if someone answer how to convert my pyspark sample code to pandas first.

Comment: What do you mean convert my pyspark sample code to pandas ? You don't know how to create panda's dataframe ?

Comment: @howie the ideia here is how to reproduce pyspark sample data from others questions. If you have to import my sample data to help me, how would you do?

Comment: I will manually create a pyspark dataframe from your sample data ~:)

Comment: I think you need a ascii txt table parser ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the following function :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

def read_spark_output(file_path):
    step1 = spark.read \
             .option("header","true") \
             .option("inferSchema","true") \
             .option("delimiter","|") \
             .option("parserLib","UNIVOCITY") \
             .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace","true") \
             .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace","true") \
             .option("comment","+") \
             .csv("file://{}".format(file_path))
    # select not-null columns
    step2 = t.select([c for c in t.columns if not c.startswith("_")])
    # deal with 'null' string in column
    return step2.select(*[when(~col(col_name).eqNullSafe("null"), col(col_name)).alias(col_name) for col_name in step2.columns])
```

It's one of the suggestions given in the following question : **[How to make good reproducible Apache Spark examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples/48454013#48454013)**.

**Note 1:** Sometimes, there might be special cases where this might not apply for some reason or the other and which can generate in errors/issues i.e [Group by column "grp" and compress DataFrame - (take last not null value for each column ordering by column "ord")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53154848/group-by-column-grp-and-compress-dataframe-take-last-not-null-value-for-eac/53279212#53279212).
So please use it with caution !

**Note 2: (Disclaimer)**  I'm not the original author of the code. Thanks to @MaxU for the code. I just made some modifications on it.

Comment: What is `file_path` here ?

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but I often face the same issue so wrote a small utility for this https://github.com/ollik1/spark-clipboard

It basically allows copy-pasting data frame show strings to spark. To install it, add jcenter dependency `com.github.ollik1:spark-clipboard_2.12:0.1` and spark config `.config("fs.clipboard.impl", "com.github.ollik1.clipboard.ClipboardFileSystem")` After this, data frames can be read directly from the system clipboard

```
val df = spark.read
  .format("com.github.ollik1.clipboard")
  .load("clipboard:///*")
```

or alternatively files if you prefer. Installation details and usage are described in the read me file.

Comment: That is advanced! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always read the data in pandas as a pandas dataframe and then convert it back to a spark dataframe. No, there is not a direct equivalent of read_clipboard in pyspark unlike pandas.

The reason is that Pandas dataframes are mostly flat structures where as spark dataframes can have complex structures like struct, arrays etc, since it has a wide variety of data types and those doesn't appear on console output, it is not possible to recreate the dataframe from the output.

Comment: it is possible to read my code example in pandas? can you show me how?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine panda read_clipboard, and convert to pyspark dataframe

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

pdDF = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',', 
                       index_col=0, 
                       names=['USER_ID', 
                              'location',
                              'timestamp',
                              ])



mySchema = StructType([ StructField("USER_ID", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("location", LongType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("timestamp", LongType(), True)])

#note: True (implies nullable allowed)


df = spark.createDataFrame(pdDF,schema=mySchema)
```

**Update:**

What @terry really want is copy ASCII code table to python , and following is 
example. When you parse data into python , then you can convert to anything.

```
def parse(ascii_table):
    header = []
    data = []
    for line in filter(None, ascii_table.split('\n')):
        if '-+-' in line:
            continue
        if not header:
            header = filter(lambda x: x!='|', line.split())
            continue
        data.append(['']*len(header))
        splitted_line = filter(lambda x: x!='|', line.split())
        for i in range(len(splitted_line)):
            data[-1][i]=splitted_line[i]
    return header, data
```

Comment: What `ascii_table` must be?