# Spark SQL Sort order not retained by GroupBy and Aggregation?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark 2.1.

If I run the following example:

```
val seq = Seq((123,"2016-01-01","1"),(123,"2016-01-02","2"),(123,"2016-01-03","3"))

val df = seq.toDF("id","date","score")

val dfAgg = df.sort("id","date").groupBy("id").agg(last("score"))

dfAgg.show
dfAgg.show
dfAgg.show
dfAgg.show
dfAgg.show
```

The output of above code is:

```
+---+------------------+
| id|last(score, false)|
+---+------------------+
|123|                 1|
+---+------------------+

+---+------------------+
| id|last(score, false)|
+---+------------------+
|123|                 2|
+---+------------------+

+---+------------------+
| id|last(score, false)|
+---+------------------+
|123|                 1|
+---+------------------+

+---+------------------+
| id|last(score, false)|
+---+------------------+
|123|                 3|
+---+------------------+

+---+------------------+
| id|last(score, false)|
+---+------------------+
|123|                 3|
+---+------------------+
```

The intention was to get the score associated with the latest date for each id:

```
+---+------------------+
| id|last(score, false)|
+---+------------------+
|123|                 3|
+---+------------------+
```

but this clearly hasn't worked as the result is non-deterministic. Do we have to use window functions to achieve this?

Comment: can you update with your expected output as well?

Comment: what version of spark do you have?

Comment: tried to regenerate the issue with spark 2.1..getting consistent result. Could you please try "dfAgg.cache" before performing show operation and let me know if inconsistency is still there?

Comment: I double checked - when I ran it the first time I got the expected result 5 times. Ran it once more and it varied! Trying the .cache as suggested seems to give a consistent result, though in the cases which I've run it consistently the 'wrong' answer when the score returned is 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the docs for org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.aggregate.Last:

```
/**
 * Returns the last value of `child` for a group of rows. If the last value of `child`
 * is `null`, it returns `null` (respecting nulls). Even if [[Last]] is used on an already
 * sorted column, if we do partial aggregation and final aggregation (when mergeExpression
 * is used) its result will not be deterministic (unless the input table is sorted and has
 * a single partition, and we use a single reducer to do the aggregation.).
 */
```

shows that unfortunately this is expected behaviour.

So in answer to my question, for now it seems like Window functions, as described [SPARK DataFrame: select the first row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878370/spark-dataframe-select-the-first-row-of-each-group) may be the best way forwards.

Answer (score -3):

You can try with `orderBy` instead of `sort` even though the javadoc says they are same

> > /**
> >        * Returns a new Dataset sorted by the given expressions.
> >        * This is an alias of the `sort` function.
> >        *
> >        * @group typedrel
> >        * @since 2.0.0
> >        */
> >       @scala.annotation.varargs
> >       def orderBy(sortCol: String, sortCols: String*): Dataset[T] = sort(sortCol, sortCols : _*)

You can try

```
val dfAgg = df.orderBy("id","date").groupBy("id").agg(last("score"))
```