# How to use collect_set and collect_list functions in windowed aggregation in Spark 1.6?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.6

In Spark 1.6.0 / Scala, is there an opportunity to get `collect_list("colC")` or `collect_set("colC").over(Window.partitionBy("colA").orderBy("colB")`?

Answer (score 35):

Given that you have `dataframe` as

```
+----+----+----+
|colA|colB|colC|
+----+----+----+
|1   |1   |23  |
|1   |2   |63  |
|1   |3   |31  |
|2   |1   |32  |
|2   |2   |56  |
+----+----+----+
```

You can `Window` functions by doing the following

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
df.withColumn("colD", collect_list("colC").over(Window.partitionBy("colA").orderBy("colB"))).show(false)
```

Result:

```
+----+----+----+------------+
|colA|colB|colC|colD        |
+----+----+----+------------+
|1   |1   |23  |[23]        |
|1   |2   |63  |[23, 63]    |
|1   |3   |31  |[23, 63, 31]|
|2   |1   |32  |[32]        |
|2   |2   |56  |[32, 56]    |
+----+----+----+------------+
```

Similar is the result for `collect_set` as well. But the order of elements in the final `set` will not be in order as with `collect_list`

```
df.withColumn("colD", collect_set("colC").over(Window.partitionBy("colA").orderBy("colB"))).show(false)
+----+----+----+------------+
|colA|colB|colC|colD        |
+----+----+----+------------+
|1   |1   |23  |[23]        |
|1   |2   |63  |[63, 23]    |
|1   |3   |31  |[63, 31, 23]|
|2   |1   |32  |[32]        |
|2   |2   |56  |[56, 32]    |
+----+----+----+------------+
```

If you remove `orderBy` as below

```
df.withColumn("colD", collect_list("colC").over(Window.partitionBy("colA"))).show(false)
```

result would be

```
+----+----+----+------------+
|colA|colB|colC|colD        |
+----+----+----+------------+
|1   |1   |23  |[23, 63, 31]|
|1   |2   |63  |[23, 63, 31]|
|1   |3   |31  |[23, 63, 31]|
|2   |1   |32  |[32, 56]    |
|2   |2   |56  |[32, 56]    |
+----+----+----+------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Has the orderBy effect here? I was told it's a non-deterministic function to be avoided (https://stackoverflow.com/q/33878370/1773841 at the end of the accepted answer) or is it ok for this case since it happens inside the withColumn?

Comment: I think its safe to do it in above way  @IgnacioAlorre. what is non-deterministic function in the above answer ?

Comment: I was doing exactly as you do in the answer, but someone point me to the link I added in the previous comment. And they say there, that it may work in local the orderBy(), but not in a distributed enviroment. I´m rather new in Spark, and I am mostly gathering opinions and recommendation, don´t take my word as I an ultimate answer, it is just what I understood from the link I posted you. If I am wrong, please let me know because I would be happy to keep using the partitionBy and orderBy inside the withColumn

Comment: I agree that I have seen inconsistency in using orderBy with groupBy. But I haven't seen inconsistency with the window function as partitionBy will partition the dataframe to be grouped into partitions and shuffle data so that each partition would be in one of the distributed node and orderBy would work on that partitioned distributed dataframe/dataset. So I don't think there would be a problem with Window function. :)

Comment: what version of Spark are you using for this example?

Comment: I am using 2.1.0 and Window function was introduced since 1.4

Comment: I don't believe this answer will work for version 1.6, since Spark 1.6 does not support using a distinct aggregate function as a window function (like collect_set).  And I believe collect_list isn't a supported window function either.

Comment: Is there any way to specify a limit parameter for each window? For example, if we only want top 5 elements (according to orderBy) from each partition on colA?

Comment: you should try rowsBetween :) @ZobayerHasan

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I don't think rowsBetween would actually work for that use case because after you did collect_list, you would have a bunch of lists with 5 elements each but you would no longer be within the orderBy so you wouldn't know which one was the top for its partition, right? Would you call first() on a second iteration of partition and orderBy then?

Answer (score 0):

Existing answer is valid, just adding here a different style of writting window functions:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val wind_user = Window.partitionBy("colA", "colA2").orderBy("colB", "colB2".desc)

df.withColumn("colD_distinct", collect_set($"colC") over wind_user)
.withColumn("colD_historical", collect_list($"colC") over wind_user).show(false)
```