# Concat multiple string rows for each unique ID by a particular order

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a table where each row is a unique ID and the Place and City column consists of all the places and cities a person visited , ordered by the date of visit , either using Pyspark or Hive.

```
   df.groupby("ID").agg(F.concat_ws("|",F.collect_list("Place")))
```

does the concatenation but I am unable to order it by the date. Also for each column I need to keep doing this step separately.

I also tried using windows function as mentioned in this post, ([collect_list by preserving order based on another variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46580253/collect-list-by-preserving-order-based-on-another-variable))
but it trows an error :java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 'collect_list(') is not supported in a window operation.
I want to :

1- order the concatenated columns in order of the date travelled

2- do this step for multiple columns

Data

```
| ID | Date | Place | City |

| 1  | 2017 | UK    | Birm |
| 2  | 2014 | US    | LA   |
| 1  | 2018 | SIN   | Sin  |
| 1  | 2019 | MAL   | KL   |
| 2  | 2015 | US    | SF   |
| 3  | 2019 | UK    | Lon  |
```

Expected

```
| ID | Place       | City          | 

| 1  |  UK,SIN,MAL |  Birm,Sin,KL  |
| 2  |  US,US      |  LA,SF        |
| 3  |  UK         |  Lon          |
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [collect\_list by preserving order based on another variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46580253/collect-list-by-preserving-order-based-on-another-variable)

Comment: Thanks. The first solution can't be used for multiple columns and the solution using windows functions throws an error :java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 'collect_list('Place) is not supported in a window operation.

Comment: What version of Spark are you using? Window functions won't work with too old versions (see e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46628459/spark-unsupportedoperationexception-collect-list-is-not-supported-in-a-window).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> from pyspark.sql import Window
>>> w = Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('Date')

//Input data frame
>>> df.show()
+---+----+-----+----+
| ID|Date|Place|City|
+---+----+-----+----+
|  1|2017|   UK|Birm|
|  2|2014|   US|  LA|
|  1|2018|  SIN| Sin|
|  1|2019|  MAL|  KL|
|  2|2015|   US|  SF|
|  3|2019|   UK| Lon|
+---+----+-----+----+

>>> df2 = df.withColumn("Place",F.collect_list("Place").over(w)).withColumn("City",F.collect_list("City").over(w)).groupBy("ID").agg(F.max("Place").alias("Place"), F.max("City").alias("City"))

 //Data value in List
>>> df2.show()
+---+--------------+---------------+
| ID|         Place|           City|
+---+--------------+---------------+
|  3|          [UK]|          [Lon]|
|  1|[UK, SIN, MAL]|[Birm, Sin, KL]|
|  2|      [US, US]|       [LA, SF]|
+---+--------------+---------------+


//If you want value in String 
>>> df2.withColumn("Place", F.concat_ws(" ", "Place")).withColumn("City", F.concat_ws(" ", "City")).show()
+---+----------+-----------+
| ID|     Place|       City|
+---+----------+-----------+
|  3|        UK|        Lon|
|  1|UK SIN MAL|Birm Sin KL|
|  2|     US US|      LA SF|
+---+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: I am using order by in windowing that will handle your order per ID. Please check w in my code(3rd line).

Comment: Throws an error :ava.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 'collect_list('Place) is not supported in a window operation.

Comment: which Spark version are you using?  Have you import all packages that I have mentioned? Are you using collect_list("Place") or collect_list(Place)?