# Spark – join first row matching conditions

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm looking for a way to join the two following Spark Datasets:

```
# city_visits:
person_id         city                timestamp
-----------------------------------------------
        1        Paris      2017-01-01 00:00:00
        1    Amsterdam      2017-01-03 00:00:00
        1     Brussels      2017-01-04 00:00:00
        1       London      2017-01-06 00:00:00
        2       Berlin      2017-01-01 00:00:00
        2     Brussels      2017-01-02 00:00:00
        2       Berlin      2017-01-06 00:00:00
        2      Hamburg      2017-01-07 00:00:00

# ice_cream_events:
person_id      flavour                timestamp
-----------------------------------------------
        1      Vanilla      2017-01-02 00:12:00
        1    Chocolate      2017-01-05 00:18:00
        2   Strawberry      2017-01-03 00:09:00
        2      Caramel      2017-01-05 00:15:00
```

So that for each row in `city_visits`, the row in `ice_cream_events` with same `person_id` and next `timestamp` value is joined, leading to this output:

```
person_id       city            timestamp  ic_flavour          ic_timestamp
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1      Paris  2017-01-01 00:00:00     Vanilla   2017-01-02 00:12:00
        1  Amsterdam  2017-01-03 00:00:00   Chocolate   2017-01-05 00:18:00
        1   Brussels  2017-01-04 00:00:00   Chocolate   2017-01-05 00:18:00
        1     London  2017-01-06 00:00:00        null                  null
        2     Berlin  2017-01-01 00:00:00  Strawberry   2017-01-03 00:09:00
        2   Brussels  2017-01-02 00:00:00  Strawberry   2017-01-03 00:09:00
        2     Berlin  2017-01-06 00:00:00        null                  null
        2    Hamburg  2017-01-07 00:00:00        null                  null
```

Closest solution I've had so far is the following, however this obviously joins every row in `ice_cream_events` that matches the conditions, not just the first one:

```
val cv = city_visits.orderBy("person_id", "timestamp")
val ic = ice_cream_events.orderBy("person_id", "timestamp")
val result = cv.join(ic, ic("person_id") === cv("person_id")
                         && ic("timestamp") > cv("timestamp"))
```

Is there a (preferably efficient) way to specify that the join is desired only on the first matching `ice_cream_events` row and not all of them?

Comment: Join like this and [filter later](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33878701/1560062) is probably the best you can do out of the box. If `ice_cream_events` is large, but small enough to fit in memory, you can create an udf, and search over optimized structure (binary tree, binary search over sorted list), but I wouldn't bother unless you experience significant performance degradation.

Comment: @zero323 thanks, that's helpful – though I was hoping for a method similar to SQL's `JOIN LATERAL` which doesn't seem to have a Spark equivalent

Answer (score 2):

A request please include `sc.parallalize` code in questions. It makes it easier to answer.

```
val city_visits = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "Paris", "2017-01-01 00:00:00"),(1, "Amsterdam", "2017-01-03 00:00:00"),(1, "Brussels", "2017-01-04 00:00:00"),(1, "London", "2017-01-06 00:00:00"),(2, "Berlin", "2017-01-01 00:00:00"),(2, "Brussels", "2017-01-02 00:00:00"),(2, "Berlin", "2017-01-06 00:00:00"),(2, "Hamburg", "2017-01-07 00:00:00"))).toDF("person_id", "city", "timestamp")
val ice_cream_events = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "Vanilla", "2017-01-02 00:12:00"),(1, "Chocolate", "2017-01-05 00:18:00"),(2, "Strawberry", "2017-01-03 00:09:00"), (2, "Caramel", "2017-01-05 00:15:00"))).toDF("person_id", "flavour", "timestamp")
```

## Solution 1:

As suggested in the comments you can first do the join which will create all possible row combinations.

```
val joinedRes = city_visits.as("C").
    join(ice_cream_events.as("I")
      , joinType = "LEFT_OUTER"
      , joinExprs =
        $"C.person_id" === $"I.person_id" &&
        $"C.timestamp"  <  $"I.timestamp"
    ).select($"C.person_id", $"C.city", $"C.timestamp", $"I.flavour".as("ic_flavour"), $"I.timestamp".as("ic_timestamp"))
joinedRes.orderBy($"person_id", $"timestamp").show
```

[image: Joined results with all rows]

And then pick the first record using a `groupBy` clause.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val firstMatchRes =  joinedRes.
    groupBy($"person_id", $"city", $"timestamp").
    agg(first($"ic_flavour"), first($"ic_timestamp"))
firstMatchRes.orderBy($"person_id", $"timestamp").show
```

[image: Joined results with just first match rows]

Now comes the trickier part. As I faced. The above join creates a ginormous upswell of data when doing the join operation. Spark has to wait till the join is finished to run the `groupBy` leading to memory issues.

## Solution 2: (Probabilistic Approach)

Use stateful joins. For this, we maintain a state in every executor that will emit only one row per executor using local states within a bloom filter.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
var bloomFilter      = breeze.util.BloomFilter.optimallySized[String](city_visits.count(), falsePositiveRate = 0.0000001)
val isFirstOfItsName = udf((uniqueKey: String, joinExprs:Boolean) => if (joinExprs) { // Only update bloom filter if all other expresions are evaluated to true. Dataframe evaluation of join clause order is not guranteed so we have to enforce this here.
    val res = bloomFilter.contains(uniqueKey)
    bloomFilter += uniqueKey
    !res
  } else false)

val joinedRes = city_visits.as("C").
    join(ice_cream_events.as("I")
      , joinType = "LEFT_OUTER"
      , joinExprs = isFirstOfItsName(
          concat($"C.person_id", $"C.city", $"C.timestamp"), // Unique key to identify first of its kind.
          $"C.person_id" === $"I.person_id" && $"C.timestamp"  <  $"I.timestamp")// All the other join conditions here.
    ).select($"C.person_id", $"C.city", $"C.timestamp", $"I.flavour".as("ic_flavour"), $"I.timestamp".as("ic_timestamp"))
joinedRes.orderBy($"person_id", $"timestamp").show
```

[image: Joined results with bloom filter]

Finally to combine results from multiple executors.

```
val firstMatchRes =  joinedRes.
    groupBy($"person_id", $"city", $"timestamp").
    agg(first($"ic_flavour"), first($"ic_timestamp"))
```