# Spark DataFrame/Dataset Find most common value for each key Efficient way

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

**Problem:**
I have a problem to map most common value of a key in spark(using scala). I have done it with RDD but don't know how to do efficiently with DF/DS(sparksql)

**dataset is like**

```
key1 = value_a
key1 = value_b
key1 = value_b
key2 = value_a
key2 = value_c
key2 = value_c
key3 = value_a
```

After spark transformation and access output should be each key with its common value

**Output**

```
key1 = valueb
key2 = valuec
key3 = valuea
```

**Tried until now:**

**RDD**

I have tried to map and reduce by group of `(key,value),count` in RDD and it makes logic but I cant translate this into sparksql(DataFrame/Dataset) (as I want minimum shuffle across network)

Here is my code for RDD

```
 val data = List(

"key1,value_a",
"key1,value_b",
"key1,value_b",
"key2,value_a",
"key2,value_c",
"key2,value_c",
"key3,value_a"

)

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("example")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

val lineRDD = sc.parallelize(data)

val pairedRDD = lineRDD.map { line =>
val fields = line.split(",")
(fields(0), fields(2))
}

val flatPairsRDD = pairedRDD.flatMap {
  (key, val) => ((key, val), 1)
}

val SumRDD = flatPairsRDD.reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)




val resultsRDD = SumRDD.map{
  case ((key, val), count) => (key, (val,count))
 }.groupByKey.map{
  case (key, valList) => (name, valList.toList.sortBy(_._2).reverse.head)
}

resultsRDD.collect().foreach(println)
```

**DataFrame , Using Windowing:** I am trying with `Window.partitionBy("key", "value")` to aggregate the `count over the window`. and thn `sorting` and `agg()` respectively

Comment: you'll need to use a window function after a group by key, value with count, sort on count and get the first ranked row. You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878370/how-to-select-the-first-row-of-each-group/

Comment: @eliasah thanks, looking for it

Comment: Sorry wrong link ! I've updated it.

Comment: I’m on my phone thus I can’t write an answer

Comment: @eliasah no problem, please write when it is possible for you

Comment: @eliasah please post your answer if it further optimizes the operation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to what I understood from your question here's what you can do

First you have to read the data and convert it to `dataframe`

```
val df = sc.textFile("path to the data file")   //reading file line by line
  .map(line => line.split("="))                 // splitting each line by =
  .map(array => (array(0).trim, array(1).trim)) //tuple2(key, value) created
  .toDF("key", "value")                        //rdd converted to dataframe which required import sqlContext.implicits._
```

which would be

```
+----+-------+
|key |value  |
+----+-------+
|key1|value_a|
|key1|value_b|
|key1|value_b|
|key2|value_a|
|key2|value_c|
|key2|value_c|
|key3|value_a|
+----+-------+
```

Next step would be to count the repetition of identical values for each key and select the value that repeated the most for each key which can be done by using `Window` function, and `aggregations` as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._                   //import Window library
def windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("key", "value")         //defining a window frame for the aggregation
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._                     //importing inbuilt functions
df.withColumn("count", count("value").over(windowSpec))     // counting repeatition of value for each group of key, value and assigning that value to new column called as count
  .orderBy($"count".desc)                                   // order dataframe with count in descending order
  .groupBy("key")                                           // group by key
  .agg(first("value").as("value"))                          //taking the first row of each key with count column as the highest
```

thus the final output should be equal to

```
+----+-------+
|key |value  |
+----+-------+
|key3|value_a|
|key1|value_b|
|key2|value_c|
+----+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, i will test shortly

Comment: commented as much possible as I could.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Thanks for the answer. Was curious the performance difference using `groupBy` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65767105/8932910) compared to `Window` function, what do you think?

Comment: great and accurate answer !

Comment: Very nice answer! Good to keep in mind that this approach will struggle with skew if a particular key-value combination occurs very often (e.g. 20+ million such records, for executors with 4GB RAM).

Answer (score 0):

What about using `groupBy`?

```
val maxFreq= udf((values: List[Int]) => {
  values.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).maxBy(_._2)._1
})

df.groupBy("key")
  .agg(collect_list("value") as "valueList")
  .withColumn("mostFrequentValue", maxFreq(col("valueList")))
```