# Pyspark / Python - Use MIN / MAX without losing columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this:

```
----------------------------------------------
| User_ID |      Timestamp      | Article_ID |
----------------------------------------------
| 121212  | 2018-01-15 10:00:00 |      1     |
| 121212  | 2018-01-15 10:05:00 |      11    |
| 121212  | 2018-01-15 10:10:00 |      12    |
| 989898  | 2018-01-15 17:30:00 |      100   |
| 989898  | 2018-01-15 17:40:00 |      200   |
| 989898  | 2018-01-15 17:50:00 |      1     |
| 989898  | 2018-01-15 17:55:00 |      11    |
|...      |                     |            |
----------------------------------------------
```

Now i want the row with the minimum Timestamp per User_ID.
The result should be:

```
----------------------------------------------
| User_ID |      Timestamp      | Article_ID |
----------------------------------------------
| 121212  | 2018-01-15 10:00:00 |      1     |
| 989898  | 2018-01-15 17:30:00 |      100   |
|...      |                     |            |
----------------------------------------------
```

I tried the following:

```
df.groupBy('User_ID').agg(F.min('Timestamp')).show()
```

That's not so bad, but the column 'Article_ID' is missing...
Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a working solution with function struct():

```
df.select('User_ID',F.struct('Timestamp','Article_ID').alias("TA")).groupBy('User_ID').agg(F.min("TA").alias("TA")).select('User_ID','TA.Timestamp','TA.Article_ID').orderBy('User_ID').limit(10).toPandas()
```

See also original source: [How to select the first row of each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878370/how-to-select-the-first-row-of-each-group)

Comment: If you use solution from another answer don't forget [required attribution](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).

Comment: thanks for the note. I added the original source...