# how to apply partition in spark scala dataframe with multiple columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following dataframe df in Spark Scala:

```
id   project  start_date    Change_date designation

1    P1       08/10/2018      01/09/2017   2
1    P1       08/10/2018      02/11/2018   3
1    P1       08/10/2018      01/08/2016   1
```

then get designation closure to start_date and less than that

Expected output:

```
id   project  start_date    designation
1      P1     08/10/2018    2
```

This is because change date 01/09/2017 is the closest date before start_date.

Can somebody advice how to achieve this?

This is not selecting first row but selecting the designation corresponding to change date closest to the start date

Comment: thanks for checking! this is not duplicate as i am not interested in knowing the first row only, i want the data as per diff logiv

Answer (score 1):

Parse dates:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val spark: SparkSession = ???
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (1, "P1", "08/10/2018", "01/09/2017", 2), 
  (1, "P1", "08/10/2018", "02/11/2018", 3),
  (1, "P1", "08/10/2018", "01/08/2016", 1)
).toDF("id", "project_id", "start_date", "changed_date", "designation")

val parsed = df
  .withColumn("start_date", to_date($"start_date", "dd/MM/yyyy"))        
  .withColumn("changed_date", to_date($"changed_date", "dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

Find difference

```
 val diff = parsed
   .withColumn("diff", datediff($"start_date", $"changed_date"))
   .where($"diff" > 0)
```

Apply solution of your choice from [How to select the first row of each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878370/how-to-select-the-first-row-of-each-group), for example window functions. If you group by `id`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"diff")

diff.withColumn("rn", row_number.over(w)).where($"rn" === 1).drop("rn").show
// +---+----------+----------+------------+-----------+----+
// | id|project_id|start_date|changed_date|designation|diff|
// +---+----------+----------+------------+-----------+----+
// |  1|        P1|2018-10-08|  2017-09-01|          2| 402|
// +---+----------+----------+------------+-----------+----+
```

Reference:

- [How to select the first row of each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878370/how-to-select-the-first-row-of-each-group)