# How to get the first and last element from column created from collect_list in Java Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

If I understand correctly
using `groupBy().agg(collect_list(column))` will get me a column of list.
How do I get the first and last element from that list to create a new column (in Spark Dataset Java)?

For first, I can do something like this

```
.withColumn("firstItem", functions.col("list").getItem(0))
```

but how do I handle empty list?

For last item, I was thinking about `size()-1`, but in Java, -1 isn't supported in Spark data set, I tried:

```
withColumn("lastItem", function.col("list").getItem(functions.size(functions.col("list")).minus(1))
```

but it will complaint something about unsupported type error.

Comment: Using `groupBy` and `collect_list` will change the order of the items. It would be better to look into the window functions where you can use `orderBy` and the `first` and `last` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To answer your questions**:

> but how do I handle empty list?

Just don't worry about it. Access to non existing index gives `NULL` (undefined) so there is no problem here.

If you want some default value use `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.coalesce` with `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit`.

> For last item, I was thinking about size()-1, but in Java, -1 isn't supported

Use `apply`, not `getItem`:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

col("list").apply(size(col("list")).minus(lit(1)));
```

**In practice**:

Just use `min`, `max` functions. [Don't replicate `groupByKey`](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html) in SQL.

**Related**:

[How to select the first row of each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878370/spark-dataframe-select-the-first-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 2):

An empty list will simply return `null` instead of any error. Do this for the last item.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
withColumn("lastItem", reverse(col("list")).getItem(0))
```