# Retrieve maximum date from sql using SparkSQL to export in JSON

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table in remote SQL database.

```
CUSTOMERID  ACCOUNTNO   VEHICLENUMBER   TAGSTARTEFFDATE
20000000    10003014    MH43AJ411       2013-06-07 13:07:13.210 
20000001    10003014    MH43AJ411       2014-08-08.19:10:11.519
20029961    10003019    GJ15CD7387      2016-07-28 19:21:54.173
20009020    10003019    GJ15CF7747      2016-05-25 18:46:55.947
20001866    10003019    GJ15CD7657      2015-07-11 15:17:14.503
20001557    10003019    GJ15CB9601      2016-05-05 16:45:58.247
20001223    10003019    GJ15CA7837      2014-06-06 14:57:42.583
20000933    10003019    MH02DG7774      2014-02-12 13:49:31.427
20001690    10003019    GJ15CD7477      2015-01-03 16:12:59.000
20000008    10003019    GJ15CB727       2013-06-17 12:36:01.190
20001865    10003019    GJ15CA7387      2015-06-24 15:01:14.000
20000005    10003019    MH02BY7774      2013-06-15 12:29:10.000
```

I want to export as JSON and this is the code snippet.

```
  val jdbcSqlConnStr = s"jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.70.15;databaseName=$db;user=bhaskar;password=welcome123;"      
  val jdbcDbTable = table1
  val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map("url" -> jdbcSqlConnStr,"dbtable" -> jdbcDbTable)).load()
//jdbcDF.show(10)
//jdbcDF.printSchema

val query = "SELECT ACCOUNTNO, collect_set(struct(`VEHICLENUMBER`, `CUSTOMERID`, `TAGSTARTEFFDATE`)) as VEHICLE FROM tp_customer_account GROUP BY ACCOUNTNO ORDER BY ACCOUNTNO"



 
 jdbcDF.registerTempTable("tp_customer_account")
 val res00 = sqlContext.sql(query.toString) 
// res00.show(10)
 res00.coalesce(1).write.json("D:/res15")
```

**Issue:**
But here the problem is that I am getting multiple `VEHICLENUMBER` because more than one `TAGSTARTEFFDATE` along with the same `VEHICLENUMBER` is present in the table.

**Want to achieve:**
So I want to retrieve the `TAGSTARTEFFDATE` which is maximum date for the same `VEHICLENUMBER`. I want to use SparkSQL query using SQLContext as I have given in the code snippet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878370/how-to-select-the-first-row-of-each-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Window functions with `dense_rank()` that goes something like this

```
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(col("VEHICLENUMBER")).orderBy(col("TAGSTARTEFFDATE").desc)
jdbcDF.withColumn("rank", dense_rank().over(windowSpec)).filter(col("rank") === 1).drop(col("rank"))
```

At the moment I'm not really sure how to express this logic with pure SQL syntax but if you are not restricted to using just SQL you can utilize this snippet.

**Edit**

Took help of a friend to get a SQL equivalent of above. Try if it works.

```
SELECT * FROM tp_customer_account WHERE dense_rank() over(partition by VEHICLENUMBER order by TAGSTARTEFFDATE) = 1
```

Comment: Please keep in touch, I will tell you the result. Although I was looking for the SQL query for sqlContect.

Comment: @BhaskarDas There is no extra dependency to use the above code so I guess you should be fine using it.

Comment: @BhaskarDas Added the SQL equivalent too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51513443/maximum-date-from-sql-table-using-sparksql-query-to-export-as-json

Comment: Please check the updated question

Comment: Thanks but I need have to add other fields too

Comment: let me check your query