# multiple column groupBy and get max value from each group (Java Spark)

Tags: java, apache-spark, max

I have a 'Dataset' in Java Spark related to cabs of a city, that among its several columns, it has :

- `day` in the form `2016-04-02`, which is the day that the cab picked up a customer.
- `vendor_id`, which is for example `1`.
- `hour` in the form form of `2` or `16`.

I want to get the hour that each vendor, each day had the maximum number of customers. So, I think I should `GroupBy` on these three columns. What I get after `GroupBy` is
[first 2 rows after I groupBy on day, vendor_id, hour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqoi3.png)  :

```
+----------+---------+----+-----+
|day       |vendor_id|hour|count|
+----------+---------+----+-----+
|2016-01-01|1        |2   |116  |
|2016-01-01|1        |1   |110  |
+----------+---------+----+-----+
```

How can I get the hour of each day of each vendor (the groups created by `GroupBy`) with the maximum count?

I have already seen that this is [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878370/how-to-select-the-first-row-of-each-group) with join, but this and other examples grouped only on one column where here I grouped on three.

If possible, I prefer Java code that uses Spark libraries, thank you for your time.

Comment: window function might help http://queirozf.com/entries/spark-dataframe-examples-window-functions

Comment: Hi @La-Tex, can you please share a complete data sample with the expected result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `Window` class as @Salim suggested and it worked. Actually, I had already seen that it could be solved with `Window` but I thought I would be easier using `join`.

```
Dataset<Row> df_dhv_grouped = df.groupBy(
                        col("day"), col("vendor_id"), col("hour")).count();

Dataset<Row> df_max_hours =df_dhv_grouped.withColumn("max_drives_hour",max("count")
                              .over(Window.partitionBy("day","vendor_id")));

df_max_hours.filter(col("count").equalTo(col("max_drives_hour")))
                        .orderBy(col("day").asc(), col("vendor_id").asc()).show();
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

La-Tex, here's a java code sample which solves the problem, from my understanding. Here we keep one single row per vendor / day. I added an extra filter to keep first row (hour based) if multiple rows still have the same count :

```
WindowSpec window = Window.partitionBy("vendor_id", "day");

Dataset<Row> withMaxDF = df.withColumn("maxCount", org.apache.spark.sql.functions.max(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col("count")).over(window))
    .where("count = maxCount")
    .withColumn("rnum",org.apache.spark.sql.functions.row_number().over(window.orderBy("hour")))
    .where("rnum = 1")
    .drop("maxCount", "rnum");

withMaxDF.show();
```

Output :

```
+-----+----------+----+---------+
|count|       day|hour|vendor_id|
+-----+----------+----+---------+
|  116|2016-01-01|   2|        1|
+-----+----------+----+---------+
```