# Deleting duplicated rows in sparklyr

Tags: r, dplyr, dt, sparklyr

I need to delete rows that are duplicated in one column based on duplicates in another column using `sparklyr`.

The **iris** data set has a number of observations for which 4 features are identical. The values for `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width` and `Species` are similar (rows only differ for `Sepal.Length` column).

Let's create a copy of **iris** in spark

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = "2.3") 

iris_spark <- copy_to(sc, iris)
```

## Base R method

This is the base R method that would remove  duplicated rows keeping only the row with the largest value for `Sepal.Length`:

```
iris_order = iris[order(iris[,'Sepal.Length'],-iris[,'Sepal.Length']),] ### sort first
iris_subset = iris_order[!duplicated(iris_order$Sepal.Length),] ### Keep highest
dim(iris_subset) # 35 5
```

but this doesn't work on `tbl_spark` object:

```
iris_spark_order = iris_spark[order(iris_spark[,'Sepal.Length'],-iris_spark[,'Sepal.Length']),]
```

> Error in iris_spark[, "Sepal.Length"] : incorrect number of dimensions

### Tidyverse

There are two possible `dplyr` solutions that I can think of which work for a `data.frame` but not `tbl_spark`:

#### 1)

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% distinct()
```

```
iris_spark %>% distinct()

Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`Sepal.Length`' given input columns: [iris.Sepal_Length, iris.Sepal_Width, iris.Petal_Width, iris.Petal_Length, iris.Species]; line 1 pos 16;
'Distinct
+- 'Project ['Sepal.Length]
   +- SubqueryAlias iris
      +- LogicalRDD [Sepal_Length#13, Sepal_Width#14, Petal_Length#15, Petal_Width#16, Species#17], false

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpression$1(QueryPlan.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.mapExpressions(QueryPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsUp(QueryPlan.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:642)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sparklyr.Invoke.invoke(invoke.scala:147)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:123)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.read(stream.scala:66)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:51)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:4)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:138)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

#### 2)

```
iris_order <- arrange(iris, Sepal.Length)
iris_subset <- iris_order [!duplicated(iris_order $Sepal.Length),]
```

but doesn't work on `tbl_spark` object:

```
library(dplyr)
iris_order <- arrange(iris_spark, Sepal.Length)
iris_subset <- iris_order [!duplicated(iris_order$Sepal.Length),]
```

> Error in iris_order[!duplicated(iris_order$Sepal.Length), ] : 
>     incorrect number of dimensions

### data.table

The `DT` solution for a `data.frame`

```
library(data.table)
df <- iris # iris resides in package that is locked so copy to new object
unique(setDT(df)[order(Sepal.Length, -Species)], by = "Sepal.Length")
```

but doesn't work on `tbl_spark` object:

```
unique(setDT(iris_spark)[order(Sepal.Length)], by = "Sepal.Length")
```

> Error in setDT(iris_spark) : 
>     All elements in argument 'x' to 'setDT' must be of same length, but the profile of input lengths (length:frequency) is: [1:1, 2:1]
>   The first entry with fewer than 2 entries is 1

So how does one *actually* accomplish this task in Spark with `sparklyr`?

Comment: I guess `filter` would work `library(dplyr); iris_spark %>% group_by(Sepal.Length) %>% filter(n() ==1)` or try with `distinct` `iris_spark %>% distinct(Sepal.Length)`

Comment: Thanks @akrun. The `library(dplyr); iris_spark %>% group_by(Sepal.Length) %>% filter(n() == 1)` solution does the trick.

I was trying the `iris_spark %>% distinct(Sepal.Length)` method last night which also tosses an error; however, I forgot to add it to this post (I'll do that now).

Comment: Yes, some methods are not yet compatible

Comment: @Matthew:  If there are two or more rows that have the same value for Sepal.length column,  akrun's solution will remove both rows.  Is this what you want, or do you want to keep at least one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filter` would work with `sparklyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(sparklyr)
iris_spark %>% 
    group_by(Sepal.Length) %>% 
    filter(n() ==1)
```

Comment: Seems like you forgot to include `arrange` ‒ right now it will take arbitrary row, not  "the row with the largest value for Sepal.Length". Also `distinct` is compatible with sparklyr ([though not very useful here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33878701/10938362)). Based on traceback it seems that OP used wrong column name (`sparklyr` doesn't support dotted names, so columns are renamed).

Comment: @user10938362  Thanks, I couldn't test because I had the java issue comptability.  Perhaps if it is backquoted, may be it works

Answer (score 1):

If the problem was as simple as stated in the question, where you want to take highest value of one column, given n - 1 grouping columns, a simple aggregation would suffice:

```r
iris_spark %>% 
  group_by(Sepal_Width, Petal_Length, Petal_Width, Species) %>% 
  summarise(Sepal_Length=max(Sepal_Length))
```

If you didn't care which value you'd get*, and number of columns would differ, you could could drop duplicates (this internally uses `first`, which cannot be used in `dplyr` without window):

```r
iris_spark %>% 
  spark_dataframe() %>% 
  invoke(
    "dropDuplicates",
    list("Sepal_Width", "Petal_Length" ,"Petal_Width", "Species")) %>% 
  sdf_register()
```

If you care about the order, [arkun's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59707038/10465355) is technically correct, but not very scalable. Instead you could combine remaining columns into a `struct` and take its `max` (`structs` use lexicographic ordering).

```r
iris_spark %>%
  group_by(Sepal_Width, Petal_Length, Petal_Width, Species) %>% 
  # You can put additional values in the struct
  summarise(values=max(struct(Sepal_Length))) %>% 
  mutate(Sepal_Length=values.Sepal_Length)
```

---

* It is important to stress out that any preceding ordering is ignored, even if toy examples might indicate otherwise.