# Sum of amounts of latest id by date PySpark

Tags: pyspark, sum

I have data like in a dataframe

| CommsId | Id | Amount | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 85 | 1 | 10 | 07/10/2020 |
| 72 | 1 | 15 | 09/09/2021 |
| 85 | 1 | 25 | 09/09/2021 |
| 70 | 1 | 30 | 09/09/2021 |
| 72 | 1 | -15 | 05/11/2020 |
| 70 | 1 | -30 | 05/11/2020 |

For each date, I want to find the sum of amounts of the latest CommsId as of the date.

Expected output is as below

| Date | Sum_Amount | Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 07/10/2020 | 10 | 1 |
| 09/09/2021 | 70 | 1 |
| 05/11/2021 | 25 | 1 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark Dataframe - How to keep only latest record for each group based on ID and Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59886143/spark-dataframe-how-to-keep-only-latest-record-for-each-group-based-on-id-and)

Comment: Hi @wwnde, I have tried that, I want to do that for each Date. How do I do that?

Comment: step 1 - retain records with the latest `CommsId` for each group. step 2 - sum up the remaining records of `Amount` at the required group level.