# How to group specific SQL columns and retrieve rows with highest counts for those columns?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, hiveql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following data:

```
col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4
-----------------------------
a1      b1      c1      d1
a1      b2      c1      d1
a1      b3      c1      d1
a1      b4      c1      d2
a1      b5      c2      d2
a1      b6      c2      d2
a1      b7      c1      d3
a1      b8      c2      d3
a1      b9      c3      d3
a1      b10     c1      d2
a1      b11     c2      d3
a2      b12     c1      d1
a3      b13     c1      d1
```

I am interested in being able to:

- Return rows where the value for `col_1` is unique
- For each row in the result, it should return the values for the columnns that have the highest counts when grouping by: `col_3`, `col_4`

For example, I would like the output to return the following:

```
col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4
-----------------------------
a1      b1      c1      d1
a2      b12     c1      d1
a3      b13     c1      d1
```

Notice in the result that each value in `col_1` is unique. Also note that for `a1`, it returned with `c1` and `d1` as they had the highest group by counts for `a1`.

How can I achieve this by SQL query? I will be using it for a Hive SQL query.

Comment: You've tagged your question with several [tag:rdbms]s. Please [edit] it and retag it only with the one you're actually using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select the first row of each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878370/how-to-select-the-first-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `row_number()` window function:

```
select t.col_1, t.col_2, t.col_3, t.col_4
from (
  select col_1, min(col_2) col_2, col_3, col_4,
    row_number() over (partition by col_1 order by count(*) desc) rn
  from tablename
  group by col_1, col_3, col_4
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e1GqYhdghffywqnQuSG7iz/1).
Results:

```
| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 |
| ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- |
| a1    | b1    | c1    | d1    |
| a2    | b12   | c1    | d1    |
| a3    | b13   | c1    | d1    |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and window functions:

```
select col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4
from (
    select
        col_1, 
        col_2, 
        col_3, 
        col_4, 
        rank() over(partition by col_1 order by count(*) desc) rn
    from mytable t
    group by col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions if you want the complete rows:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by col1 order by cnt desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by col1, col3, col4) as cnt
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The innermost subquery  counts the number of rows for each col1/col3/col4 combination.  The middle subquery enumerates the rows the highest count for each `col1`.  The outermost filters for the highest count.