# Spark: getting the first entry according to a date groupBy

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to get the first `Datetime` of each day from a certain dataframe?

Schema:

```
root
 |-- Datetime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Quantity: integer (nullable = true)


+-------------------+--------+
|           Datetime|Quantity|
+-------------------+--------+
|2021-09-10 10:08:11|     200|
|2021-09-10 10:08:16|     100|
|2021-09-11 10:05:11|     100|
|2021-09-11 10:07:25|     100|
|2021-09-11 10:07:14|    3000|
|2021-09-12 09:24:11|    1000|
+-------------------+--------+
```

Desired output:

```
+-------------------+--------+
|           Datetime|Quantity|
+-------------------+--------+
|2021-09-10 10:08:11|     200|
|2021-09-11 10:05:11|     100|
|2021-09-12 09:24:11|    1000|
+-------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select the first row of each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878370/how-to-select-the-first-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number` for that. Simply define a Window partitioned by day and ordered by `Datetime`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = Window.partitionBy(F.to_date("Datetime")).orderBy("Datetime")

df1 = df.withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(w)).filter("rn = 1").drop("rn")

df1.show()
#+-------------------+--------+
#|           Datetime|Quantity|
#+-------------------+--------+
#|2021-09-10 10:08:11|     200|
#|2021-09-11 10:05:11|     100|
#|2021-09-12 09:24:11|    1000|
#+-------------------+--------+
```