# How to remove duplicates and nulls if non-null exists in group?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, filter, group-by

The follow DataFrame should be filtered based on the **flag** column. If the group based on columns **id** and **cod** doesn't have any row with value different of **None**, it's necessary to maintain just a unique row, otherwise, it's necessary to remove the row with **None** value in column **flag**.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, row_number,max

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Vazio').getOrCreate()

data = [('1', 10, 'A'),
('1', 10, 'A'),
('1', 10, None),
('1', 15, 'A'),
('1', 15, None),
('2', 11, 'A'),
('2', 11, 'C'),
('2', 12, 'B'),
('2', 12, 'B'),
('2', 12, 'C'),
('2', 12, 'C'),
('2', 13, None),
('3', 14, None),
('3', 14, None),
('3', 15, None),
('4', 21, 'A'),
('4', 21, 'B'),
('4', 21, 'C'),
('4', 21, 'C')]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = ['id', 'cod','flag'])
df.show()
```

How could I obtain the next DataFrame based on last one using PySpark?

```
+---+---+----+
| id|cod|flag|
+---+---+----+
|  1| 10|   A|
|  1| 15|   A|
|  2| 11|   A|
|  2| 11|   C|
|  2| 12|   B|
|  2| 12|   C|
|  2| 13|null|
|  3| 14|null|
|  3| 15|null|
|  4| 21|   A|
|  4| 21|   C|
+---+---+----+
```

Comment: Do you have a pandas or pyspark dataframe?

Comment: Pyspark, I did with pandas because I do not have spark in this computer yet.

Comment: Input: `('4', 21, 'A')`, `('4', 21, 'B')`, `('4', 21, 'C')`, `('4', 21, 'C')`. In the output you only have `('4', 21, 'A')` and `('4', 21, 'C')`. Is it a mistake in Output? Why `('4', 21, 'B')` is removed?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the edited question:

```py
df = df.groupBy('id', 'cod').agg(F.collect_set('flag').alias('flag'))
df = df.withColumn(
    'flag',
    F.explode(F.when(F.size('flag') != 0, F.col('flag')).otherwise(F.array(F.lit(None))))
)
df.show()
# +---+---+----+
# | id|cod|flag|
# +---+---+----+
# |  2| 11|   C|
# |  2| 11|   A|
# |  2| 12|   C|
# |  2| 12|   B|
# |  1| 15|   A|
# |  1| 10|   A|
# |  3| 14|null|
# |  4| 21|   C|
# |  4| 21|   B|
# |  4| 21|   A|
# |  2| 13|null|
# |  3| 15|null|
# +---+---+----+
```

<sup>Note that the group (4, 21) contains all the 3 flags A, B, C. In the description of the question, you haven't mentioned leaving just 2 values, but in the example somehow the B was deleted, so I assumed it as a mistake.</sup>

---

Answer to the original question:

```py
df = df.groupBy('id', 'cod').agg(F.max('flag').alias('flag'))
```

You couldn't just remove duplicates based on columns id and cod, as there's no guarantee that you will always get a value from column flag which is not null.

Comment: I changed the question, your answer was right.

Comment: @PedroHenrique - I have updated the answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

this could be a solution

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.values.tolist() not in new_df.values.tolist():

        if row["flag"] is None and row.values.tolist()[:2] in new_df[list(new_df.columns)[:2]].values.tolist():
            continue

        new_df.loc[-1] = row.values.tolist()
        new_df.index += 1
```

at the end you could just add

```
df = new_df.copy(deep=True)
del new_df
```

Comment: I changed the question, your answer was right.

Answer (score 0):

With `PySpark`. Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33878701/15239951) (Spark)

```
window = Window.partitionBy(['id', 'cod']).orderBy(col('flag').desc())
out = (df.withColumn('row',  row_number().over(window))
         .filter(col('row') == 1).drop('row'))
out.show()

# Output
+---+---+----+
| id|cod|flag|
+---+---+----+
|  2| 11|   A|
|  2| 12|   B|
|  1| 15|   A|
|  3| 14|null|
|  2| 13|null|
|  3| 15|null|
|  1| 10|   A|
+---+---+----+
```

Setup

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, row_number

data = [['1', 10, 'A'],
        ['1', 10, 'A'],
        ['1', 10, None],
        ['1', 15, 'A'],
        ['1', 15, None],
        ['2', 11, 'A'],
        ['2', 12, 'B'],
        ['2', 12, 'B'],
        ['2', 13, None],
        ['3', 14, None],
        ['3', 14, None],
        ['3', 15, None]]

columns = ['id', 'cod', 'flag']
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)
df.show()

# Output
+---+---+----+
| id|cod|flag|
+---+---+----+
|  1| 10|   A|
|  1| 10|   A|
|  1| 10|null|
|  1| 15|   A|
|  1| 15|null|
|  2| 11|   A|
|  2| 12|   B|
|  2| 12|   B|
|  2| 13|null|
|  3| 14|null|
|  3| 14|null|
|  3| 15|null|
+---+---+----+
```

Comment: I changed the question, your answer was right.