# remove duplicates from a DataFrame, and keep all columns from that row

Tags: python, pyspark

I am attempting to use pyspark to de-duplicate a DataFrame.  Here is the DataFrame:

```
employee_name   department      start_date                  favorite_color
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
James           sales           2023-11-03T12:38:02.371076Z green
James           sales           2020-01-03T12:38:02.371076Z red
Fred            operations      2023-09-27T16:28:01.920063Z red
Fred            leadership      2023-07-04T16:28:01.920063Z green
Fred            operations      2023-10-27T16:28:01.920063Z green
Wilma           administrative  2021-06-17T16:28:01.920063Z green
```

If `employee_name` and `department` are identical, it is considered a duplicate and only the row with the most recent `start_date` should be kept.

This gets me close:

```
deduped_df = employee_df.groupBy(col("employee_name"), col("department")).agg(max(col("start_date")))

employee_name   department      start_date                  
-----------------------------------------------------------
Fred            leadership      2023-07-04T16:28:01.920063Z
Fred            operations      2023-10-27T16:28:01.920063Z
James           sales           2023-11-03T12:38:02.371076Z
Wilma           administrative  2021-06-17T16:28:01.920063Z
```

...however, it doesn't preserve the `favorite_color` column, and I can't figure out how to preserve it because the `group_by` clause eliminates it from the DataFrame.

Is there a way I can use `start_date` as the criteria for which row to keep, and keep all columns from the row that is kept?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878370/how-to-select-the-first-row-of-each-group

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the Window function on the Dataframe.

First we prepare test df

```
data = [
    {"employee_name": "James", "department": "sales", "start_date": "2023-11-03T12:38:02.371076Z", "favorite_color": "green"},
    {"employee_name": "James", "department": "sales", "start_date": "2020-01-03T12:38:02.371076Z", "favorite_color": "red"},
    {"employee_name": "Fred", "department": "operations", "start_date": "2023-09-27T16:28:01.920063Z", "favorite_color": "red"},
    {"employee_name": "Fred", "department": "leadership", "start_date": "2023-07-04T16:28:01.920063Z", "favorite_color": "green"},
    {"employee_name": "Fred", "department": "operations", "start_date": "2023-10-27T16:28:01.920063Z", "favorite_color": "green"},
    {"employee_name": "Wilma", "department": "administrative", "start_date": "2021-06-17T16:28:01.920063Z", "favorite_color": "green"}
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
```

Define a window for the specification: employee_name and department are identical, it is considered a duplicate and only the row with the most recent start_date should be kept.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, col
window_spec = Window.partitionBy("employee_name", "department").orderBy(col("start_date").desc())
```

Assign row_number for rows in each partition based on the orderBy clause and select the first row_number in each partition

```
result_df = (df.withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(window_spec))
.filter(col("row_number") == 1)
.drop("row_number"))
```

View the result df

```
result_df.show()

+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+
|    department|employee_name|favorite_color|          start_date|
+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+
|    leadership|         Fred|         green|2023-07-04T16:28:...|
|    operations|         Fred|         green|2023-10-27T16:28:...|
|         sales|        James|         green|2023-11-03T12:38:...|
|administrative|        Wilma|         green|2021-06-17T16:28:...|
+--------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+
```